# Magento Enterprise CatalogEvent

Tags: magento, enterprise

I'm working on an extension that will receive CatalogEvent information from Magento (Enterprise) when saved and do custom processing on the information.

Here's the code I use to listen to the event:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <global>
    <models>
        <mage4ucustomredirect>
             <class>Mage4u_Customredirect</class>
        </mage4ucustomredirect>
    </models>
    <events>
       <enterprise_catalogevent_event>
            <observers>
                <abc>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Mage4u_Customredirect_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>on_enterprise_catalogevent_event</method>
                </abc>
            </observers>
       </enterprise_catalogevent_event>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

and this is the observer:

```
class Mage4u_Customredirect_Model_Observer
{
    public function on_enterprise_catalogevent_event(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {  
        Mage::log( "on_enterprise_catalogevent_event" );
    }

}
?>
```

When I save the CatalogEvent, I do not receive the call. Can you spot any problems with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your observer isn't called, because `enterprise_catalog_event` is a **model**, but not an *event*.

See `app/code/core/Enterprise/CatalogEvent/etc/config.xml`:

```
<config>
    :
    <global>
        <models>
            <enterprise_catalogevent>
                <class>Enterprise_CatalogEvent_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>enterprise_catalogevent_resource</resourceModel>
            </enterprise_catalogevent>
            <enterprise_catalogevent_resource>
                :
                <entities>
                    <event>
                        <table>enterprise_catalogevent_event</table>
                    </event>
                    :
                </entities>
            </enterprise_catalogevent_resource>
        </models>
        :
    </global>
    :
</config>
```

Afaik `enterprise_catalogevent/event` does not dispatch its own save events, but you could observe the generic `model_save_before` or `model_save_after` event, to receive callbacks whenever such model is being created/saved.

You just need to identify the object being passed to these generic events first:

```
$oObject = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
if ($oObject instanceof Enterprise_CatalogEvent_Model_Event) {
    if ($oObject->isObjectNew()) {
        // it is/was a create
    else {
        // it is/was a save
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks. now I see why it's not working... but do you know which event I should tap into so I can receive a callback whenever a CatalogEvent is being created/saved?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<events>
   <enterprise_catalogevent_event>
        <observers>
            <mage4u_customredirect_model_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Mage4u_Customredirect_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>on_enterprise_catalogevent_event</method>
            </mage4u_customredirect_model_observer>
        </observers>
   </enterprise_catalogevent_event>
</events>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried it... nothing has changed. Can you confirm that the event name I'm using is correct? I mean "enterprise_catalogevent_event"

Comment: try this event trigger: catalogevent_event_save_after